# Wordpress display file include / partial path information for debuging

Tags: wordpress, debugging, filepath, partial, include-path

Few months back I was working on customizing theme that I was assigned to. I remember that **I used some function or define something in the config or theme functions file and than it displayed debug information of exact path to every included file/partial** but I cannot remember what it was. I am googling for hours with no luck and I am running out of time (deadline).

When I set it it displayed path or url/uri to included files in currently opened file. Something like this but it also normally rendered the page. There was just this lines of debug information in it.

```
THEMEROOT/header.php
THEMEROOT/footer.php
and other partials
```

Now I have to customize very complex theme based on some kind of framework with hundreds of files and I am completely lost in it. I cannot find the location I need to change to achieve what I have to achieve.

I want to somehow dump this theme includes path but cannot remember how to do it and I running out of time. I've been googling for hours but did not find anything and it feels like a waste of valuable time.

Could someone please help me or point me at right direction? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what I was looking for but someone on another site reminded me of `get_included_files()` php function which does what I need. Just wanted to give some info in case someone else has this problem too.